# java.lang.Double cannot be cast to abie47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am encountering the `"java.lang.Double cannot be cast to abie47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap"`  error when opening the app with my android while using `react-native-gifted-charts`.

This error showing after using react-native-gifted charts
this is the code of the screen, can anyone help or advise what could be the problem and ways to resolve it

[Error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFJ7k.jpg)

Below is the code

```
import styles from "./styles";
import CoinDetailedHeader from "./components/CoinDetailedHeader/index";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { ChartDot, ChartPath, ChartPathProvider, ChartYLabel } from "@rainbow-me/animated-charts";

const CoinDetailedScreen = () => {
  const {
    image: { small },
    name,
    symbol,
    prices,
    market_data: { market_cap_rank, current_price, price_change_percentage_24h, },
  } = Coin;

  const [coinValue, setCoinValue] = useState("1");
  const [usdValue, setUsdCoinValue] = useState(current_price.usd.toString());

  const percentageColor = price_change_percentage_24h < 0 ? '#ea3943' : '#16c784';
  const chartColor = current_price.usd > prices[0][1] ? '#16c784' : '#ea3943';
  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

  const changeCoinValue = (value) => {
    setCoinValue(value);
    const floatValue = parseFloat(coinValue) || 0;
    setUsdCoinValue((floatValue * current_price.usd).toString());
  };

  const changeUsdValue = (value) => {
    setUsdCoinValue(value);
    const floatValue = parseFloat(value.replace(',', '.')) || 0;
    setCoinValue((floatValue / current_price.usd).toString());
  }

  const formatCurrency = (value) => {
    "worklet";
    if (value === "") {
      return `$${current_price.usd.toFixed(2)}`
    }
    return `$${parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)}`
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
      <ChartPathProvider data={{
        points: prices.map(([x, y]) => ({ x, y })),
        smoothingStrategy: 'bezier',
      }}>
        <CoinDetailedHeader
          image={small}
          symbol={symbol}
          marketCapRank={market_cap_rank}
        />
        <View style={styles.priceContainer}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.name}>{name}</Text>
            <ChartYLabel
              format={formatCurrency}
              style={styles.currentPrice}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: percentageColor, paddingVertical: 8, paddingHorizontal: 3, borderRadius: 5, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <AntDesign name={price_change_percentage_24h < 0 ? 'caretdown' : 'caretup'}
              size={12} color={'white'} style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginRight: 5 }} />
            <Text style={styles.priceChange}>{price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}%</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <ChartPath height={screenWidth / 2} strokeWidth={2} stroke={chartColor} width={screenWidth} />
        <ChartDot style={{ backgroundColor: chartColor }} />
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', alignSelf: 'center' }}>{symbol.toUpperCase()}</Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} value={coinValue} keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={changeCoinValue} />
          </View>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', alignSelf: 'center' }}>USD</Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} value={usdValue} keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={changeUsdValue} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </ChartPathProvider>
    </View>

  );
};

export default CoinDetailedScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating following packages to mentioned versions

```
"react-native-linear-gradient": "2.6.2",
"react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
```

Ref : [java.lang.Double cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap](https://github.com/Abhinandan-Kushwaha/react-native-gifted-charts/issues/263#issuecomment-1230016926)